# android thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Tags: android, sqlite

strong textI am using eclipse with android sdk r18 to do some database action:

I have a view called "advance_search" and stores some data about request calls.

Now i want to poll out some records from database using a simple rawquery function.
BUT I FAILED! Don't know why!!

can anyone give me some advice?

Logs:

```
05-11 06:37:11.057: E/Status(1306): Database Initialize OK!
05-11 06:37:11.098: E/Status(1306): Starting Database Check procedure
05-11 06:37:11.098: E/Status(1306): Database already exist!
05-11 06:37:11.117: E/Status(1306): Open Database OK
05-11 06:37:11.117: E/LogSQLProcess(1306): String id is :6326
05-11 06:37:11.138: E/LogSQLProcess(1306): SQLiteDatabase in READ MODE!
05-11 06:37:11.148: E/LogSQLProcess(1306): DB Query Logon_info View complete!
05-11 06:37:11.148: E/LogSQLProcess(1306): Cursor moved to Position 0!
05-11 06:37:11.148: E/LogSQLProcess(1306): USER Name is John
05-11 06:37:11.168: D/AndroidRuntime(1306): Shutting down VM
05-11 06:37:11.168: W/dalvikvm(1306): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TicketDroid.PKG/com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search.onCreate(User_Search.java:105)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-11 06:37:11.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1306):     ... 11 more
```

com.TicketDroid.PKG/com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search is MY JAVA file

Codes for database action:

```
    public Cursor UserSearch(String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "String id is :"+id);
    SQLiteDatabase dbs = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "SQLiteDatabase in READ MODE!");
    String selectionArgs[] = new String[] {id};
    Cursor n=dbs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM logon_info WHERE _id= ?", selectionArgs);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "DB Query Logon_info View complete!");
    n.moveToPosition(0);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "Cursor moved to Position 0!");
    String name=n.getString(0);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "USER Name is "+name);
    String Args[] = new String[] {name};
    return dbs.rawQuery("select * from advance_search where REQUEST_PERSON= ?", Args);
```

I've tested the sql statement in sqlite3 NAD DEFINITELY SURE IT WORKS!

---

Sorry to cause inconvenience!

Here is the full code:

DBInitialize.java

```
 public class DB_Initialize extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.TicketDroid.PKG/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "TicketDroid";
private static String DB = "TicketDroid";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;  
private final Context myContext;    
public static String LOGON_TABLE = "LOGON";
public static String LOGON_VIEW = "logon_info";
public static String TICKET_VIEW = "advance_search";


public DB_Initialize(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    Log.e("Status", "Database Initialize OK!");
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.e("Status", "Create Database in REAED MODE");

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String Path = DB_PATH + DB;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Log.e("Status", "Starting Database Check procedure");

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("Status", "Database doesn't exist!");
        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();
        Log.e("Status", "Database already exist!");

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    Log.e(" Status :","Prepare to copy database!" );

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    } 
    Log.e("Status", "Copy Database file complete");
    //Close the streams
    Log.e(" Status :","Prepare to Close file stream!" );
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    Log.e("Status", "Closed file stream!");

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Log.e("Status", "Open Database OK");

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        Log.e("Status", "Database closed");
        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public Cursor UserSearch(String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "String id is :"+id);
    SQLiteDatabase dbs = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "SQLiteDatabase in READ MODE!"); 
    String selectionArgs[] = new String[] {id};
    Cursor n=dbs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM logon_info WHERE _id= ?", selectionArgs);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "DB Query Logon_info View complete!");
    n.moveToPosition(0);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "Cursor moved to Position 0!");
    String name=n.getString(0);
    Log.e("LogSQLProcess", "USER Name is "+name);
    n.close();
    String Args[] = new String[] {name};
    return dbs.rawQuery("select * from advance_search where REQUEST_PERSON= ?", Args); }
```

User_search.java

```
public class User_Search extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button srhu_back,srhu_next,srhu_previous;
TextView tv_result;

String Password;
String Type;
String ID;



Integer count=0;
Cursor srh = null;
ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>(); 
String str[]={};
String strg="";


String[] rset=new String[] {
      "REQUEST_PERSON","USER_EXT",
        "DEPARTMENT_CODE","EMAIL_ADDR",
        "_id","TICKET_Title",
        "PROBLEM_SOFT","CATEGORY",
        "SYMPTONS","CONTACT",
        "STATUS","FINISH_DATE","ACTIONS",
        "ENGINEER1","ENGINEER1_EXT",
        "ENGINEER1","ENGINEER1_EXT",
};


String res = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_search);
    srhu_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.srhu_bBack);
    srhu_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.srhu_bNext);
    srhu_previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.srhu_bPrevious);
    tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srhu_tvresult);
    srhu_back.setOnClickListener(this);
    srhu_next.setOnClickListener(this);
    srhu_previous.setOnClickListener(this);



    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();     
      Password=bundle.getString("Password");
      Type=bundle.getString("Type");
      ID=bundle.getString("ID");   



        DB_Initialize srh_ret = new DB_Initialize(User_Search.this);

           try {     
               srh_ret.createDataBase();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {          
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");            
            }
            try {
                srh_ret.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                throw sqle;
            }

                try {
                    srh=srh_ret.UserSearch(ID);
                }                   
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(User_Search.this, "Cannot Fetch any records!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } finally {             

                    for(srh.moveToFirst(); srh.moveToNext(); srh.isAfterLast()) {
                        // The Cursor is now set to the right position
                        for(int i=0; i<=16; i++) {
                            if (srh.isNull(i)) strg="N/A"; 
                            else strg=srh.getString(i);
                            res = res+rset[i]+ " : "+strg+"\n"; 
                            Log.e("TextString","result is "+res+"\n");
                        }
                        array.add(res);  
                    }

                }
                tv_result.setText(str[count]);  
                count++;
    Toast.makeText(User_Search.this, "Record Searching Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  }
```

Logs :

```
05-11 09:18:29.807: D/dalvikvm(370): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2553K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 60ms
05-11 09:18:35.807: W/KeyCharacterMap(370): No keyboard for id 0
05-11 09:18:35.807: W/KeyCharacterMap(370): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-11 09:18:39.187: E/Status(370): Database Initialize OK!
05-11 09:18:39.237: E/Status(370): Starting Database Check procedure
05-11 09:18:39.247: E/Status(370): Database already exist!
05-11 09:18:39.268: E/Status(370): Open Database OK
05-11 09:18:39.287: E/LogSQLProcess(370): SQLiteDatabase in READ MODE!
05-11 09:18:39.287: E/LogSQLProcess(370): SQLiteQueryBuilder created!
05-11 09:18:39.297: E/LogSQLProcess(370): SQLiteQueryBuilder set Table!
05-11 09:18:39.297: E/LogSQLProcess 0(370): John
05-11 09:18:39.297: E/LogSQLProcess 1(370): john
05-11 09:18:39.306: E/LogSQLProcess 2(370): USER
05-11 09:18:39.306: E/LogSQLProcess 3(370): 6326
05-11 09:18:39.306: V/CursorValues(370): Johnjohn
05-11 09:18:39.306: V/CursorValues After Moved to First(370): Johnjohn
05-11 09:18:39.306: V/Values(370): John/john
05-11 09:18:39.306: V/CursorValues Now(370): Johnjohn
05-11 09:18:39.306: E/Check Logon Process(370): user and password entered correct!
05-11 09:18:39.306: E/Check Logon Process(370): JohnjohnUSER6326
05-11 09:18:39.326: E/Status(370): Database closed
05-11 09:18:39.337: V/USER TYPE SELECT :(370): USER
05-11 09:18:41.927: E/Status(370): Database Initialize OK!
05-11 09:18:41.946: E/Status(370): Starting Database Check procedure
05-11 09:18:41.946: E/Status(370): Database already exist!
05-11 09:18:41.966: E/Status(370): Open Database OK
05-11 09:18:41.966: E/LogSQLProcess(370): String id is :6326
05-11 09:18:41.997: E/LogSQLProcess(370): SQLiteDatabase in READ MODE!
05-11 09:18:41.997: E/LogSQLProcess(370): DB Query Logon_info View complete!
05-11 09:18:41.997: E/LogSQLProcess(370): Cursor moved to Position 0!
05-11 09:18:41.997: E/LogSQLProcess(370): USER Name is John
05-11 09:18:42.018: D/AndroidRuntime(370): Shutting down VM
05-11 09:18:42.018: W/dalvikvm(370): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TicketDroid.PKG/com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search.onCreate(User_Search.java:122)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-11 09:18:42.027: E/AndroidRuntime(370):  ... 11 more
05-11 09:18:46.587: I/Process(370): Sending signal. PID: 370 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Before posting, ask yourself "Is this post easy to read?"... if the answer is "no", then format it better.

Comment: Also, when reading your stack trace, pls include the area listed as causing the error, i.e. the part around `com.TicketDroid.PKG.User_Search.onCreate(User_Search.java:105)` that is causing your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thanks! I will attach the full code later (NOT Yet asked for 8 hrs)! But do you have any ideas why this would happen? I searched the code but don't found a clue. All arrays are initialized

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

in your onCreate method.

Before performing `n.moveToPosition(0);` check first if it is not empty ... do this by

```
if(n.moveToFirst()==true) {
     String name = n.getString(n.getColumnIndex(<column name>));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but the error still existed! I tried enter a condition that definitely can fetch records out. So this may not be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you debug the app so that Eclipse will break when the Exception is encountered. Then you can look at all your variables and the stack calls to see what you missed. It's somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but maybe I don't familiar with eclipse, so I cannot pin point the problem statement! Would you mind tutoring me?